# Regularly polling multiple API for a push notification iOS App

Tags: php, push-notification, polling

I apologize in advance if this question is too subjective.

I am working on an iOS app that allows users to search through multiple API's to find a result, and then get a push notification when results similar to the ones the user signed up for are found in those APIs.

I am comfortable with the iOS part of the app, but what I am curious about is how should I handle polling multiple API's regularly to see if any of the signed up for topics have received a new item.

The first thing that I imagine is that if a user signs up, for example, to receive notifications when a new X is available, I would have a web server that would go through each of the signed up topics for each user every X minutes, if there is a new result then send a push notification to the user. Even though I have little experience doing such a thing, I know that this will probably be very taxing on the server, and will only get worse as the user base expands.

So rather than periodically querying the API's in the background, how could I go about doing this? As far as I know, the API's I would be use do not allow for push notifications to my server from the API.

Thanks in advance,

Will